# How do I add a description to a table from the command line?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am massing copying government open data to BigQuery, see https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/freeopendata-161213:copy_of_socrata_data and https://github.com/wayeasycorp/FreeOpenData/blob/master/etl/socrata/copy_all_datasets.py Using the command line how do I add a description to a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

`bq update --description "Description of the table" dataset.table`

PS: I assumed that you have installed `google cloud SDK` and configured it correctly